# asp.net c# code works (from VS2022 and on IIS10) on local machine to connect to SQL Server DB it does not work on Webserver

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, plesk

I don't get it why my (very simple) code is working properly on my local machine from Visual Studio 2022 and on the local IIS 10 to connect to a sql server express (15) and on my webserver it's not. I'm sure that's a really simple quesion for you.

What I'm tryin' to do is a simple login page. My code in the Login.aspx is:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=BERLIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=membersarea; User ID=sa;Password=Test2022!");
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select * from useraccount where username=@userName and passWord=@Password", con);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", tbxUsername.Text.ToString());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passWord", tbxPassword.Text.ToString());
                SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(datatable);
                con.Open();
                int i = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                if (datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Session["userName"] = tbxUsername.Text.ToString();
                    datatable.Dispose();

                    Response.Redirect("Content.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Benutzername oder Passwort falsch.";
                    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                    lblMessage.Visible = true;

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

(I know that I'm not supposed to do this with the sa account, just to keep it simple... The only thing I do on the web server is to change the name of the sql server instance. Management Studio works fine with this User Id and Password on my web server. I installed the sql server using Plesk and I don't think it is working properly within plesk. Using the Management Studio I can restore backups, queries, create new accounts, etc.)

[image: SQL Management Studio on web server]

My Content.asps says Hi (including my name) and shows the Logout-Button. If you enter credentials that are not correct it says so and if you try to go to the content-Page without loggin' in you're redirected to the Login-page. That is what I want. Trouble is, it's not workin' on my webserver. It is simply doin' nothing. No error message, or something else. It takes a while, password is cleared again and username is still there. (Doesn't matter which credentials are used.)

I don't think that it comes to the first line of my code, and I don't know why. Are there DLLs that are needed, or what else did I forget? I'm pretty sure this is a absolute beginner problem but I can't figure it out.

Tried to fill in some code to alter the lblMessage, to find out where the problem starts, but nothing of it is displayed.

Comment: Your web server knows nothing about `BERLIN\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: Put some logging in your `catch` block so you know what the exception details are. It will probably point you (or us) right to the problem but right now you are flying blind.

Comment: Are you saying that you are able to use SQL server studio to open, see, and run queries against the database running on that web server? (I doubt that). So, when you publish to the web server, you also have to get the new database name, and logon required for that instance of sql server running on that web site. So, more details as to how you created and up-loaded the database to the server will be required here. And assuming pleask, then it should display the databases, and the user + password + instance name of sql server running on that web site.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy: You're right my web server knows nothing about BERLIN\SQLEXPRESS, so as I wrote I altered the instance name (to WIN-SERVER-AL\MSSQLSERVER2019). Since it a add-feature-installation by Plesk the name of the instance is not SQLEXPRESS but MSSQLSERVER2019, eventhough I downgraded it to SQL Express by using the upgrade-installation-feature of the SQL Server 2019 Installation Center. Otherwise it would ask for a licence key.

Comment: @Crowcoder: That's a very good idea. Thank you! I always wondered how should one try to figure out what happens by himself, if you're not knowing anything. Do you have a code snippet for me for this particular question? Something, that I could add to the catch block?

Do I understand it it right? Like: `lblMessage.Text = ex.ToString();`?

Do you know a simple tutorial how to do that kind of "debugging"? I'm pretty sure I will need that quite often, in the future. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: I understand that you doubt that, but that's how it ist. Don't know how add pictures in the comment so I uploaded the screenshot of SQL Management Studio running on my web server in my question above.

I set a password for the user sa by using windows authentication, added a new user 'User1' and gave him dbreader on my "data base" which is one table, two rows and three columns, as you can see on the picture.

I did a backup of my data base as *.bak, uploaded it via FileZilla and restored it via SQL Management Studio.

Comment: showing me a picture of some table working on your local computer is of ZERO value here. The issue is what is the the database SERVER name and instance on the web site, not on your computer which is going to be VAST different. You need to get from plesk the database "instance" name for the web site - not on your local computer. That web site does not have "WIN-SERVER-AL\MSSQLSERVER2019" as the data server name. This would ONLY be the case if that server is the one server that is running your web site, but then you would not be using or care about plesk.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: I'm using 'sa' in my connection string just to be sure, that no user rights are causing the problem. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: the issue is not the sa user for the connection, the issue is what is the database server name on the web site, not the one you are using on your local computer to build the database.

Comment: I hope you're not really storing user passwords in plain text in the database...

Comment: @Albrecht there are a number of logging libraries you can use. But for simplicity, you could create an error page (I'm not sure if you are using webforms, MVC, Razor Pages, etc.) and redirect to it, passing the error message to display on a label. Just don't expose exception details after you are done debugging.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: As I wrote in my answer to your comment it is in fact the table on the **web server** and NOT on my machine. The sql server instance on the web server is: WIN-SERVER-AL\MSSQLSERVER2019. And yes, this server is running the sql server instance and my web site. I'm using Plesk because I don't know better, for instance how to create sub domains. I guess there is an easy way to do that without Plesk, but I don't know how. My bad.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: I just wrote that in addition to mention, that I know that there is a lot of work to do, like using another sql user that is not sys admin.

Comment: @Julian: That's true, I shouldn't do that. I'm just starting here, with my project. There should be a short tutorial showing how to hash it. :-) But I deal with that tomorrow. By the way, what is the state of the art way to store that connection string?

Comment: @Albrecht I would recommend to read https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html for password storage.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Thanks again. I'm using webforms, and I think that checking that check box while creating the project caused the whole problem. I have a <name-of-web-site>.dll in the bin folder. And so what Roman Ryzhiy said is true. My web server does not know anything about my sql server instance on my local machine. I tried to pass it pass it through, but nothing appeared. I don't know yet why that is but is the same way when I use the dll for the web server on my local computer. Just nothing happens, except the clearing of the pwd text box. Thank you for your food for thought! It helped a lot.

Comment: @Julian: Thank you for the link. I will read through that carefully.

Comment: Ok, that's all good then. I just wanted you to be sure that that database name and connection's on the server have to be correct - and looking at your troubles, it looks like you had that information correct.  Most web hosting server names are really ugly looking names - and your looked oh so nice and clean.  I mean, if you can logon or remote into that server directly, then get sql studio installed, and you be in great shape.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble started when I checked the pattern web forms while creating the project. In the bin folder there is a "name-of-my-project".dll and a "name-of-my-project".pdb file. Those two are generated if you recreate your project. I'm pretty sure you guys know that - I did not. Or better I do know that they were generated, but not that they are necessary. (As I wrote before, I'm at the very beginning.)

In guess that in this *.pdb and/or *.dll the connection string is stored, too. When I recreate my project with the valid connection string for the web server and upload them, too - everything works as expected. Thank you, guys for your ideas.